# How to end a sequence by simply typing "end"

Tags: java

can you help me to solve this one problem in Java. All I want is terminating the program by simply typing "end" when I prompt user to input anything in any number of Lines. I search through google but I can't do anything to solved this by my own. I'm just a beginner in programming especially writing Java program.

```
int nom;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number max. is 10:");
    nom = input.nextInt();

    if ( nom > 10){
        System.out.println("Sorry you exceed the limit of number of lines!");
        System.exit(0); //
    }
    String[] Nput = new String[nom];
    for(int counter = 0; counter < nom; counter ++ ) {
        System.out.println("Input anything here in line:" +(counter+1));
        Nput[counter] = input.next();

    }
    input.close();
    System.out.println("Number of lines is:" + nom + "\r\nYou typed:");
    for(int counter = 0; counter < nom; counter ++ ) {
        System.out.println(Nput[counter]);
```

Comment: `if("end".equals(input.next())` ?

Comment: @vincrichaud this is correct. Also, he needs to terminate the loop. so, should include break keyword as well

Comment: Hint: learn about java naming conventions. variable names go camelCase, always. And they should be meaningful and help the human reader. So use names that say what they mean, like: numbersFromUser for example, instead of "Nput".

Comment: Nice ! Thank you guys. I achieved what I want. I passed on this earlier, but I messed up, if not for you  I can't make it.

Answer (score 1):

Update the for loop as follows, where you input the strings and check whether the given string is equal to the "end" or whatever your breaking condition is. Then use the transfer keyword **break** to jump from the for loop.

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < nom; counter ++ ) {
   System.out.print("Input anything here in line " +(counter+1)+" : ");
   Nput[counter] = input.next();
   if(Nput[counter].equals("end")){
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated, you literally fixed the program.